# Run Time Error 5 - Excel Date Slicer

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to add a slicer to a pivot table. I'm successfully creating the slicer cache from the pivot table, but the slicer itself gets hung up on either a Run Time Error 483 (Object Doesn't Support this property or method) or a Run Time Error 5 (Invalid Procedure call or Argument).  The latter is occurring with following configuration of the code.  The error occurs with the line `Set slicer = .Slicers.Add(pvt, , "Date", "date", 200, 250, 200, 200)`

```
Option Explicit

Sub SVBsweep_pivot()

Dim wb As Workbook
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim pvtws As Worksheet
Dim scrcdatar As Range
Dim scrcdatas As String
Dim pvt As PivotTable
Dim pf As PivotField
Dim pvtcache As PivotCache
Dim slccache As SlicerCache
Dim slicer As slicer

Set wb = ActiveWorkbook
Set ws = ActiveSheet
ws.Name = "data"
Set pvtws = Sheets.Add
pvtws.Name = "pivot"

With ws
Set scrcdatar = Range(.Cells(1, 1), .Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell))
scrcdatas = .Name & "!" & scrcdatar.Address(ReferenceStyle:=xlR1C1)
Set pvtcache = ActiveWorkbook.PivotCaches.Create(xlDatabase, scrcdatas)
End With

Set pvt = pvtcache.CreatePivotTable(pvtws.Range("A3"), "Payroll")

With pvt
    .PivotFields("Transaction").Orientation = xlColumnField
    .PivotFields("Sweep Product").Orientation = xlRowField
    .AddDataField .PivotFields("Amount"), "SumAmount", xlSum
    .DataBodyRange.NumberFormat = "_(* #,##0.00_);_(* (#,##0.00);_(*  - ??_);_(@_)"
    .ColumnGrand = True
    .RowGrand = False

    For Each pf In pvt.RowFields
        pf.DrillTo pf.Name
    Next pf
    For Each pf In pvt.ColumnFields
        pf.DrillTo pf.Name
    Next pf

End With

With wb
    Set slccache = .SlicerCaches.Add2(pvt, "Date", "Date", xlTimeline)
    With slccache    
        Set slicer = .Slicers.Add(pvt, , "Date", "date", 200, 250, 200, 200)
    End With
    With pvtws
        .Shapes.Range(Array("Date")).Select
    End With
End With
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Slicers.Add Method (Excel)` Syntax is:

`expression.Add(SlicerDestination, Level, Name, Caption, Top, Left, Width, Height)`

You have a `PivotTable` as the `SlicerDestination`

Replace these lines:

```
With wb
    Set SlcCache = .SlicerCaches.Add2(Pvt, "Date", "Date", xlTimeline)
    With SlcCache
        Set Slicer = .Slicers.Add(Pvt, , "Date", "date", 200, 250, 200, 200)
    End With
    With PvtWs
        .Shapes.Range(Array("Date")).Select
    End With
End With
```

with these lines:

```
Set SlcCache = wb.SlicerCaches.Add2(Pvt, "Date", "Date", xlTimeline)
Set Slicer = SlcCache.Slicers.Add(PvtWs, , "Date", "date", 200, 250, 200, 200)
PvtWs.Shapes.Range(Array("Date")).Select
```

Comment: Thank you for the explanation of where I went wrong, much appreciated.